# mat-icon appears in grey color in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I would like to show mat-icon in red color but it always appear in grey color. Is there a way to show mat-icon in red color? If somebody knows the please let me know. Thank you

```html
<mat-icon
    *ngIf="form.hasError('required', 'name') && isNameSubmitted"
    class="mdi mdi-24px mdi-alert-circle"
    matSuffix>
</mat-icon>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done as follow:

```
.mat-form-field .mat-icon {
   color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Often the default warn colour is red when using an Angular Material Theme. In such cases you can use:

`<mat-icon color="warn">icon</mat-icon>`

This is often a good practice when using material components as it will affect other parts of the element you might not think to style manually.

Answer (score 0):

The `angular material` way to do it is to use the built in colors:

```
<mat-icon color="primary">clear</mat-icon>
<mat-icon color="accent">clear</mat-icon>
<mat-icon color="warn">clear</mat-icon>
```